# How can I make sure a Youtube video can be embedded and playable?

Tags: api, youtube-api, google-data-api

Using Youtube API v3, there are two parameters when searching for videos: `videoSyndicated` and `videoEmbeddable`. Do I need to set them both to `true` if I want to make sure the video will play when it is embedded on my site? (I have a feeling `videoEmbeddable` is still going to give me some videos that won't play on my site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set both of those to be true, and set the regionCode parameter to reflect the region of the person doing the search, that's the best you can do for now.